# Separated at birth?

Tags: discussion, winterbash-2015

[image] [image]

> [Andrew Leach](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/18696/andrew-leach) ♦ and [Colin Fine](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/547/colin-fine)

It's uncanny! The handsome rugged features, the piercing gaze... could it be?

Comment: If someone can suggest a funnier one liner, feel free to edit! :)

Comment: Except that it's forbidden to edit out the bit about the handsome rugged features. (+1 for noticing the resemblance, though!)

Comment: Er, is your meta always like this during Binter Wash?

Comment: Perfect! I would just remove the smileys.

Comment: Yay! Seven days later, she gets a monkey hat.

Comment: What is the question about? Some two photos, one edited... There are too little tags.